# bubble pressure calculation using pc saft

Tags: python, temperature, pressure

I am trying to calculate bubble point pressure of Methane-Benzene binary mixture at 421.05 K using following code.

I am getting solution error "SolutionError: A solution was not found for flashTQ. T=421.05"

Can anyone help me to sort this out?
[My python sode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTLk3.png)

The expected answer is 24 MPA.

The experimental data is taken from source: H.-M. Lin, H. M. Sebastian, J. J. Simnick, and K.-C. Chao, “Gas-liquid equilibrium in binary mixtures of methane with N-decane, benzene, and toluene,” J. Chem. Eng. Data, vol. 24, no. 2, pp. 146–149, Apr. 1979.

Comment: Please update the question with the error message and source code.

Comment: Hi, please avoid attaching your code samples as images, as they are hard to read and not indexed by search engines. Follow the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers